# What exactly does 服侍我大脚 means?

Tags: terminology

Chinese is my native language but this is the first time I heard about this term.  What does it means?  It's used in a sentence as follow:

```
我的三个小美人，不要怕，只要你们乖乖听话，用心服侍我大脚，有你们享得福
```

Does it actually means to take good cares of his feet (like literally)?

Comment: I can't understand either, maybe more relevant contexts are needed. Is it a network novel?

Comment: @songyuanyao The above is the only reference (maybe i am bad with goolging hah) online I found using the term, while I heard it from my relative today.  It sorts of implying the idea of "serve me as an inferior" but I am not sure

Comment: At my first glance, two possibilities come to my mind: 1) 大脚 is the name of the speaker. 2) 大脚 just means "big feet" literally, as many sex games begin with licking feet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rongshuxia.com/chapter/bookid-5909417-chapterid-77641.html

In this context, it literally means that the speaker wants three cats to stroke his feet. Perhaps he is barefoot, and it would feel great to have smooth cat fur caressing the feet.

Comment: Hm it seems like there's nothing special about it, just what it means literally.  Thanks for all the helps

Comment: No, according to the context, it' just a name. Such as `老远听到土狗头大脚兴奋的说话声`, `灰毛和土狗头大脚说`, `要想活命的就乖乖地跟着咱们头大脚混，大脚不会亏待俘虏的。`... @Alex

Comment: You are right, it seems to reference this kennel owner Bigfoot in the larger context.